# Kinematic join for parallel axis rotation with equal inverse angles

Tags: kinematics

I'm looking to manufacture a coffee table. I would like the top panel of the table to be split into two parts in order to open the top of the table and get access to a cabinet. Each part of the top panel will have a vertical rotation axis and therefore the two rotation axis will be parallel. The rotation angles should be equal in opposite directions.[image] The joint should be hidden below the coffee table. It should be quite flat: maximum 5 to 10 cm. A joint with 3 parallel gears, with one gear on each axis and the third in the middle would work... but the gears would need to have large diameters as the axis would be distant by around 50 - 100 cm.

Do you have better ideas? Maybe with an endless screw in the middle?

Comment: smaller gears linked by a chain.

Comment: How many degrees of rotation do you need/want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you care about accurate angles displacement you could use chains or belts.

### Configuration 1 - Belt Not accurate

If then rotation angles **don't** have to be the same you can get away with using an cross belt drive. See below for the difference between open and cross belt drives and how the cross belt ensure the opposite direction.

[image]

### **Configuration 2: belt or chain**

another configuration is the following Red and blue are the shafts that you are interested to rotate.

[image]

You could use the configuration above with chains (although  you'd need to be able to adjust the tension on one of the yellow pulleys). If you used chain, then you'd be able to get exactly opposite angular rotations.

### Configuration 3: combination gear and chain/belt

If you need the axles to rotate exactly the same, one way the following:

[image]

- axle that carries B and C is the motor.
- A and B are gears
- C and D can be belt or chain (depending on the angular displacement requirements.